# CaptainCasa framework: DOF reactOnInstanceSelect conflicting with clickable items in the grid

Tags: jsp, captaincasa

In a few DOF grids I have icons and buttons with click actions added using a DOF extension. I also want to trigger another action when single-clicking on a grid row (reactOnInstanceSelect). I want to avoid triggering the reactOnInstanceSelect action when clicking on the icons/buttons.

Right now when I click on a button, both the button event and the reactOnInstanceSelect event are fired. <strike>The event sequence seems to be random.</strike> (in my case both events opened a popup, and the resulting popup sequence is random, the event fire sequence is not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function...

```
List<FacesEvent> requestEvents = ThreadData.getInstance().getRequestEvents();
```

...which gives you all events that are contained in a roundtrip. Could you try this one to find out in the "reactOnInstanceSelect" if another event occurs in parallel?

By the way: the event sequence is driven by the sequence of components in the component hierarchy.